# highcharts with mvc C# and sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

Have checked and rechecked for about 2 days (ug) and cannot find any guide, source, reference or documentation on using Highcharts in an MVC4/5 C# model that shows how to set up the controller / model to pull data from a SQL database.

I have this sample working -- static data typed into the controller. http://www.nimbo.com/blog/how-to-use-highcharts-js-with-asp-net-mvc-4/

All the samples (from Highcharts and the ports available via nuget) use static data. Can't find anything that shows a step-by-step for setting up the data connection and pulling in the data so it shows up in a chart. It may exist and I can't find it.

I have a db set up. Other pages are connected to the db and working -- full read/write.

But the basic chart setup has me stumped. One good example (with comments/instructions) of how to set up the connection, retrieve data, and set up an array(s) would be so very helpful.

Comment: I too would like to know how to do this. The examples show static array data being passed in as a new object, however, you can not pass an existing array into the Data() class

Comment: Has this been resolved? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Marty, I do not have a resolution for this. It wasn't essential for the project, so I put it aside.

Answer (score 1):

You need to preapre script which i.e return data as json, then in javascript use `$.getJSON()` function and get your data. Last step is use your data in highcharts.

Further information: [highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing/)

Comment: Sebastian, I had looked at those examples. Unfortunately, the environment and assumptions don't translate very well to what I have, C# MVC and SQL. 

A php example with Javascript doesn't actually answer the question I have ... which is getting the data connection established and functional in my C# MVC and SQL environment. 

Seems to me, I should not need "some other script" nor should it be necessary to rewrite my application. I would think it should be possible to set up whatever is needed within my controller and call the result from a view.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I am looking for exactly the same thing. I just came across dotnet.highcharts. You can find the code here http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com. Perhaps this will work for you as well.