# How can I generate a real-time highchart from my database data?

Tags: ajax, json, highcharts

I have looked at the following links [Binding json result in highcharts for asp.net mvc 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27741908/binding-json-result-in-highcharts-for-asp-net-mvc-4) , [highcharts with mvc C# and sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300321/highcharts-with-mvc-c-sharp-and-sql?rq=1), [HighChart Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sdorzak/HsWF2/) and many others. However, I couldn't find a working demo showing how to implement a highchart using data from a database.

**Objective:**
I want to generate a real time highchart line graph getting data from my database. What I want is very similar to the third link which provides a real-time highchart with randomly generated values. It is also similar by X-axis and Y-axis, for I want my x-axis to be "Time" (I have a DateTime column in my database) and y-axis to be an integer (I have a variable for that as well in my database).

Please I need help in sending the model data to my razor view.

Note that I am already using SignalR to display a realtime table. I also want to know if it can be used to automatically update the highchart as well.

Below is the code snippet of my script in the view. I have used the code provided in link 3 for generating the highchart. Please tell me where should I apply the changes on my code.

```
@section Scripts{
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
        <script src="~/SignalR/Hubs"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
                var notifications = $.connection.dataHub;

                //debugger;
                // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
                notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
                    getAllMessages()
                };
                // Start the connection.
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    alert("connection started")
                    getAllMessages();
                }).fail(function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                });
                //Highchart
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    global: {
                        useUTC: false
                    }
                });
                //Fill chart
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'spline',
                        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                        marginRight: 10,
                        events: {
                            load: function () {
                                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                                var series = this.series[0];
                                setInterval(function () {
                                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                        y = Math.random();
                                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                                }, 1000);//300000
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Live random data'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                        tickPixelInterval: 150
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Value'
                        },
                        plotLines: [{
                            value: 0,
                            width: 1,
                            color: '#808080'
                        }]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                                Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                                Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Random data',
                        data: (function () {
                            // generate an array of random data
                            var data = [],
                                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                                i;

                            for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                                data.push({
                                    x: time + i * 1000,
                                    y: Math.random()
                                });
                            }
                            return data;
                        }())
                    }]
                });

            });
            function getAllMessages() {
                var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
                var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))

        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/GetMessages',
            data: {
                id: data.id,
            },
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'

        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
            $("#g_table").dataTable();
        }).error(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
            }
        </script>
    }
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
//Highchart
Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
   useUTC: false }
 });
//Fill chart
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
  renderTo: 'container',
  defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
  events: {
      load:  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
      alert("Chart connection started")
      var point = getAllMessagesforChart();
      var series = this.series[0];
      setInterval(function (point) {

         // add the point
         series.addPoint([point.date_time, point.my_value], true, true)

         }, 1000);
           }).fail(function (e) {
                   alert(e);
                               })
                           }
                        }
        title: {
        text: 'Live random data'
                   },
        xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                        },
        yAxis: {
        minPadding: 0.2,
        maxPadding: 0.2,
        title: {
            text: 'Value',
            margin: 80
                           }
                       },
        series: [{
              name: 'Random data',
              data: []
                       }]
                    });


function getAllMessagesforChart() {
                var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Model))

        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/GetMessagesforChat',
            data: {
                id: data.id,
            },
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'

        }).success(function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            //data_graph = [].concat(data);
            //$("#debug").html(data_graph);

        }).error(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });

                return data;
                //return data_graph;
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry but, where do you get the database stuff? And what is the database looking like?

Comment: First of all, I have an entity framework where I connected the ms sql database to my web application. And for the real-time table SignalR I have created a model class just like the method provided by this link http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/ . 
So basically I am not sure if I should use the EF or the other used for signalR in order to generate the highchart.
As for my database, it is a simple table consisting of 3 columns an id, datetime and integer value.

Comment: The simplest scenario. 1) Prepare script which communicate with database and return json with point. 2). Catch load event in highcharts, like in example. Instaed of using math.random, call ajax to url with custom script from point 1. 3) add point to chart.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the steps. But I have two question for the second step, you meant that I call the ajax from "load: " part, but what happens withe "series:" part I believe this is making it real so what should I put in there. 
And since I am a newbie in json, I would appreciate it if you provide me with some code for the first step or a link.
Thank you @SebastianBochan

Comment: I mean something like this, http://jsfiddle.net/zcogcjyx/, but obviosuly you need to adapt data.x / data.y to fields which you have in your json.

Comment: Okay I understand the Json part now, but still didn't get what should I do in the "series:" part where the values are randomly generated here. Or is it the case where I dont need the series: part anymore because it updates on its own if my data are updated?

Comment: I applied what I understood but I am not getting any line on the graph I will add my updated code. Please can you check it and point any error @SebastianBochan

Comment: 1) Use ajax and then initialise chart in callback, because it seems that your syntax is incorrect. Let me know how your output data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example that might help you:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-ajax/
```

it uses an ajax callback function.

Well, you can also have a look at my sample where I add dynamically series by clicking add button.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/Sh71yN?p=preview
```

You only need to add data in the right structure.

Have a look at the function

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function()
```

of my code script.js

I hope it helps.
regards,
Luis